# Sending mail in php its got failed

Tags: php

I'm getting

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: are your smtp credentials valid? can you paste in your mail snippet?

Comment: Have you verified your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or tried to use `ini_set()`?

Comment: You're trying to use localhost as smtp server.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

> The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the
>   Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for
>   composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a
>   MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the
>   localhost or a remote machine).

Try
1) PHPmailer,etc
2) Try Test Mail Server Tool, etc

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Bigden